How can access the pointer values passed to and returned by C functions from Python?
Can my python code have access to the actual pointer values received and returned by C functions called through ctypes?
If yes, how could I achieve that ?

I'd like to test the pointer values passed to and returned from a shared library function to test an assignment with pytest (here, to test that strdup didn't return the same pointer but a new pointer to a different address).
I've wrapped one of the functions to implement (strdup) in a new C function in a file named wrapped_strdup.c to display the pointer values and memory areas contents:
/*
** I'm compiling this into a .so the following way:
**   - gcc -o wrapped_strdup.o -c wrapped_strdup.c
**   - ar rc wrapped_strdup.a wrapped_strdup.o
**   - ranlib wrapped_strdup.a
**   - gcc -shared -o wrapped_strdup.so -Wl,--whole-archive wrapped_strdup.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *wrapped_strdup(char *src){
    char *dst;

    printf("From C:\n");
    printf("- src address: %X, src content: [%s].\n", src, src);
    dst = strdup(src);
    printf("- dst address: %X, dst content: [%s].\n", dst, dst);
    return dst;
}

I also create in the same directory a pytest test file named test_strdup.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes
import pytest

# Setting wrapped_strdup:
lib_wrapped_strdup = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./wrapped_strdup.so")
wrapped_strdup = lib_wrapped_strdup.wrapped_strdup
wrapped_strdup.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
wrapped_strdup.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("src", [b"", b"foo"])
def test_strdup(src: bytes):
    print("")
    dst = wrapped_strdup(src)

    print("From Python:")
    print(f"- src address: {hex(id(src))}, src content: [{src!r}].")
    print(f"- dst address: {hex(id(dst))}, dst content: [{dst!r}].")
    
    assert src == dst
    assert hex(id(src)) != hex(id(dst))


Then, running my test gives me the following output:
$ pytest test_strdup.py --maxfail=2 -v -s
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.5, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/MRe_strdup_test_with_ctypes
plugins: anyio-4.4.0, cov-5.0.0, typeguard-4.3.0
collected 2 items                                                                          

test_strdup.py::test_strdup[] 
From C:
- src address: C19BDBE8, src content: [].
- dst address: 5977DFA0, dst content: [].
From Python:
- src address: 0x75bcc19bdbc8, src content: [b''].
- dst address: 0x75bcc19bdbc8, dst content: [b''].
FAILED
test_strdup.py::test_strdup[foo] 
From C:
- src address: BF00A990, src content: [foo].
- dst address: 59791030, dst content: [foo].
From Python:
- src address: 0x75bcbf00a970, src content: [b'foo'].
- dst address: 0x75bcbefc18f0, dst content: [b'foo'].
PASSED

========================================= FAILURES =========================================
______________________________________ test_strdup[] _______________________________________

src = b''

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("src", [b"", b"foo"])
    def test_strdup(src: bytes):
        print("")
        dst = wrapped_strdup(src)
    
        print("From Python:")
        print(f"- src address: {hex(id(src))}, src content: [{src!r}].")
        print(f"- dst address: {hex(id(dst))}, dst content: [{dst!r}].")
    
        assert src == dst
>       assert hex(id(src)) != hex(id(dst))
E       AssertionError: assert '0x75bcc19bdbc8' != '0x75bcc19bdbc8'
E        +  where '0x75bcc19bdbc8' = hex(129453562518472)
E        +    where 129453562518472 = id(b'')
E        +  and   '0x75bcc19bdbc8' = hex(129453562518472)
E        +    where 129453562518472 = id(b'')

test_strdup.py:22: AssertionError
================================= short test summary info ==================================
FAILED test_strdup.py::test_strdup[] - AssertionError: assert '0x75bcc19bdbc8' != '0x75bcc19bdbc8'
=============================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.04s ================================


This output shows two things :

Addresses for variables referencing b'' in Python are identical either way (that's the same object) despite addresses being different from the lower level perspective. This is consistent with some pure Python tests and I guess it could be some optimization feature.
Addresses values from C and Python for dst and src variables don't actually seem related.

So the above attempt is actually unreliable to check that a function returned a pointer to a different area.

I could also try to retrieve the pointer value itself and make a second test run for checking this part specifically by changing the restype attribute :
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                      

import ctypes
import pytest

# Setting wrapped_strdup:                                                                   
lib_wrapped_strdup = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./wrapped_strdup.so")
wrapped_strdup = lib_wrapped_strdup.wrapped_strdup
wrapped_strdup.restype = ctypes.c_void_p   # Note that it's not a c_char_p anymore.
wrapped_strdup.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("src", [b"", b"foo"])
def test_strdup_for_pointers(src: bytes):
    print("")
    dst = wrapped_strdup(src)

    print("From Python:")
    print(f"- retrieved dst address: {hex(dst)}.")


The above gives the following output :
$ pytest test_strdup_for_pointers.py --maxfail=2 -v -s
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.5, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/MRe_strdup_test_with_ctypes
plugins: anyio-4.4.0, cov-5.0.0, typeguard-4.3.0
collected 2 items                                                                          

test_strdup_for_pointers.py::test_strdup_for_pointers[] 
From C:
- src address: E15BDBE8, src content: [].
- dst address: 84D4D820, dst content: [].
From Python:
- retrieved dst address: 0x608984d4d820.
PASSED
test_strdup_for_pointers.py::test_strdup_for_pointers[foo] 
From C:
- src address: DEC7EA80, src content: [foo].
- dst address: 84EA7C40, dst content: [foo].
From Python:
- retrieved dst address: 0x608984ea7c40.
PASSED

==================================== 2 passed in 0.01s =====================================

Which would give the actual address (or at least something that looks related).
But without knowing the value the C function receives, it's not of much help.

Addendum: what I came up with from Mark's answer (and that works):
Here's a test that implements both the solution suggested in the accepted answer :
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes
import pytest

# Setting libc:
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
strlen = libc.strlen
strlen.restype = ctypes.c_size_t
strlen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)

# Setting wrapped_strdup:
lib_wrapped_strdup = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./wrapped_strdup.so")
wrapped_strdup = lib_wrapped_strdup.wrapped_strdup
# Restype will be set directly in the tests.
wrapped_strdup.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("src", [b"", b"foo"])
def test_strdup(src: bytes):
    print("")  # Just to make pytest output more readable.

    # Set expected result type.
    wrapped_strdup.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

    # Create the src buffer and retrieve its address.
    src_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(src)
    src_addr = ctypes.addressof(src_buffer)
    src_content = src_buffer[:strlen(src_buffer)]

    # Run function to test.
    dst = wrapped_strdup(src_buffer)

    # Retrieve result address and content.
    dst_addr = ctypes.addressof(dst.contents)
    dst_content = dst[: strlen(dst)]

    # Assertions.
    assert src_content == dst_content
    assert src_addr != dst_addr

    # Output.
    print("From Python:")
    print(f"- Src content: {src_content!r}. Src address: {src_addr:X}.")
    print(f"- Dst content: {dst_content!r}. Dst address: {dst_addr:X}.")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("src", [b"", b"foo"])
def test_strdup_alternative(src: bytes):
    print("")  # Just to make pytest output more readable.

    # Set expected result type.
    wrapped_strdup.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

    # Create the src buffer and retrieve its address.
    src_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(src)
    src_addr = ctypes.addressof(src_buffer)
    src_content = src_buffer[:strlen(src_buffer)]

    # Run function to test.
    dst = wrapped_strdup(src_buffer)

    # Retrieve result address and content.
    dst_addr = dst
    # cast dst:
    dst_pointer = ctypes.cast(dst, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
    dst_content = dst_pointer[:strlen(dst_pointer)]

    # Assertions.
    assert src_content == dst_content
    assert src_addr != dst_addr

    # Output.
    print("From Python:")
    print(f"- Src content: {src_content!r}. Src address: {src_addr:X}.")
    print(f"- Dst content: {dst_content!r}. Dst address: {dst_addr:X}.")

Output :
$ pytest test_strdup.py -v -s            
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.14, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /home/vmonteco/.pyenv/versions/3.10.14/envs/strduo_test/bin/python3.10
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/MRe_strdup_test_with_ctypes
plugins: anyio-4.4.0, stub-1.1.0
collected 4 items                                                                 

test_strdup.py::test_strdup[] 
From C:
- src address: 661BBE90, src content: [].
- dst address: F5D8A7A0, dst content: [].
From Python:
- Src content: b''. Src address: 7C39661BBE90.
- Dst content: b''. Dst address: 57B4F5D8A7A0.
PASSED
test_strdup.py::test_strdup[foo] 
From C:
- src address: 661BBE90, src content: [foo].
- dst address: F5E03340, dst content: [foo].
From Python:
- Src content: b'foo'. Src address: 7C39661BBE90.
- Dst content: b'foo'. Dst address: 57B4F5E03340.
PASSED
test_strdup.py::test_strdup_alternative[] 
From C:
- src address: 661BBE90, src content: [].
- dst address: F5B0AC50, dst content: [].
From Python:
- Src content: b''. Src address: 7C39661BBE90.
- Dst content: b''. Dst address: 57B4F5B0AC50.
PASSED
test_strdup.py::test_strdup_alternative[foo] 
From C:
- src address: 661BBE90, src content: [foo].
- dst address: F5BF9C20, dst content: [foo].
From Python:
- Src content: b'foo'. Src address: 7C39661BBE90.
- Dst content: b'foo'. Dst address: 57B4F5BF9C20.
PASSED

================================ 4 passed in 0.01s ================================


A return type of ctypes.c_char_p is "helpful" and converts the return value to a Python string, losing the actual C pointer.  Use ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char) to keep the pointer.
A return type of ctypes.c_void_p is also "helpful" and converts the returned C address to a Python integer, but can be cast a more specific pointer type to access the data at the address
To find it's address, use ctypes.addressof on the contents of the pointer; otherwise you get the address of the storage of the pointer.
I use char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src) as an example because the returned pointer is the same address as the dest pointer and it shows the C addresses are the same from Python without needing a C helper function.
In the code below the mutable string buffer dest has the same address as the return value and a few ways to examine the C address of the return value are shown:
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')

dll.strcpy.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.c_char_p
dll.strcpy.restype = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)  # NOT ct.c_char_p to keep pointer
dll.strlen.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
dll.strlen.restype = ct.c_size_t

dest = ct.create_string_buffer(10)  # writable char buffer
print(f'{ct.addressof(dest) = :#x}')  # its C address
result = dll.strcpy(dest, b'abcdefg')

# Note that for strcpy, returned address is the same as dest address
print(f'{ct.addressof(dest) = :#x}')  # dest array's C address
print(f'{ct.addressof(result.contents) = :#x}')  # result pointer's C address (same as dest)
n = dll.strlen(result)
print(f'{result[:n] = }')  # must slice char* or only prints one character.
print(f'{dest.value = }')  # array has .value (nul-termination) or .raw

dll.strcpy.restype = ct.c_void_p  # alternative, get the pointer address as Python int
result = dll.strcpy(dest, b'abcdefg')
print(f'{result = :#x}')  # same C address as above
p = ct.cast(result, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char))  # Cast afterward
print(f'{ct.addressof(p.contents) = :#x}')  # same C address
n = dll.strlen(p)
print(f'{p[:n] = }')  # must slice char*

p = ct.cast(result, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char * n))  # alternate, pointer to sized array
print(f'{p.contents.value = }')  # don't have to slice, (char*)[n] has known size n

Output:
ct.addressof(dest) = 0x1abe80ea398
ct.addressof(dest) = 0x1abe80ea398
ct.addressof(result.contents) = 0x1abe80ea398
result[:n] = b'abcdefg'
dest.value = b'abcdefg'
result = 0x1abe80ea398
ct.addressof(p.contents) = 0x1abe80ea398
p[:n] = b'abcdefg'
p.contents.value = b'abcdefg'


Thank you. This works and I implemented both these solutions in a snippet I added to my post.
